# Getting error in Vmware "pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available."

Tags: python, django, openssl, pip

I am struggling in installing Django using pip on Vmware. I have tried almost every option available.

Command:

```
[root@ora12c src]# pip3.6 install django
```

Output:

```
[root@ora12c src]# pip3.6 install django
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting django
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)': /simple/django/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)': /simple/django/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)': /simple/django/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)': /simple/django/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)': /simple/django/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/django/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for django
```

pip version:

```
[root@ora12c src]# pip3.6 -V
pip 9.0.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
```

Python version:

```
[root@ora12c src]# python3.6 -V
Python 3.6.5
```

I also downloaded the openssl file but no avail

```
wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1-pre7.tar.gz
```

Comment: First verify your network works: `ping pypi.org` from vmware.

Comment: Checked and its working[root@ora12c ~]# ping pypi.org
PING pypi.org (151.101.64.223) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 151.101.64.223: icmp_seq=3 ttl=49 time=77.0 ms
^C
--- pypi.org ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2100ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 77.030/98.135/127.423/21.372 ms

Comment: `python3.6 -c "import ssl;print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)"`? Also, you downloaded *OpenSSL*, but did you **install** it (or have it installed)? `openssl version`.

Comment: @Cristi - Getting error while importing SSL certs- [root@ora12c Python-3.6.5]# python3.6 -c "import ssl;print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 101, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ssl'. The openssl version is showing correct- [root@ora12c Python-3.6.5]# openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1-pre7 (beta) 29 May 201. However, the version in yum info and SSH version seems different -

Comment: [root@ora12c Python-3.6.5]# yum info openssl
Installed Packages
Name        : openssl
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 1.0.1e
Release     : 48.el6
Size        : 4.0 M
Repo        : installed

[root@ora12c Python-3.6.5]# ssh -V
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013

Comment: Hmm, try reinstalling the *Python* pkg. Unfortunately, I forgot the *yum* command, and I don't have a *RH* based machine to try it on :( .